# How is fork() able to produce varied results?

Tags: c, output, fork

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
    int x = 1;

   /* fork off a child process */
    if (fork()==0)
       x++;

    /* fork off another child process */
    if (fork()==0)
       x++;

    printf("x = %d : ", x); fflush(stdout);

    /* wait for a signal to be received */
    pause();
}
```

This gives different results every time I run it. I've tried reading about why, but I'm having trouble wrapping my head around it. What are the possible outputs of this? And why?

Comment: Depend in the order what process is getting executed

Comment: @Ed Heal, I've seen people say "I've implemented X" meaning "I've implemented code which calls X" ("I've used X") a number of times. I suspect it's a mistranslation. Yes, it's incorrect, but there are better ways of letting people know that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The output of each process is completely deterministic (assuming no errors).

```
P1                        P11                       P111
+----------------+        + - - - - - - - -+        + - - - - - - - -+
|  x = 1;        |        :  x = 1;        :        :  x = 1;        :
|  fork(); // !0 |------->:  fork(); // =0 :        :  fork(); // =0 :
|  fork(); // !0 |---+    |  ++x;          |        :  ++x;          :
|  printf();     |   |    |  fork(); // !0 |------->:  fork(); // =0 :
+----------------+   |    |  printf();     |        |  ++x;          |
                     |    +----------------+        |  printf();     |
                     |                              +----------------+
                     |
                     |    P12
                     |    + - - - - - - - -+
                     |    :  x = 1;        :
                     |    :  fork(); // !0 :
                     +--->:  fork(); // =0 :
                          |  ++x;          |
                          |  printf();     |
                          +----------------+
```

- P1 outputs `1`.
- P11 outputs `2`.
- P111 outputs `3`.
- P12 outputs `2`.

However, depending on variations in scheduling, the order in which each process's output appears is unpredictable.

Comment: A good  diagram for the explanation. Wish I could give extra for the description!

Comment: `++x` is `x++` in the original question.

Comment: @Simson, You may have noticed that the boxes don't contain the exact code in other respects either. I wrote the effect of the code rather than actual code.

Comment: Woah, this diagram helps a lot! Thank you! I appreciate you putting the code to be executed in each box. That really helps me visualize what happens a lot better. Sounds like the scheduling is what's causing the varied results then, and that would explain why it always prints a combination of the same 4 digits.

Comment: Yup, exactly. Never be afraid to take out a pencil and a piece of paper and trace out what's happening. Welcome.